# Same MySQL query runs much slower in 5.6 than in 5.1

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.1

I am encountering a strange issue where this particular MySQL query that we have would run almost 50 times slower after we upgraded our database from MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.6.23.

This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT `companies`.*
FROM   `companies` 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `company_texts` 
                ON `company_texts`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` 
                   AND `company_texts`.`language` = 'en' 
                   AND `company_texts`.`region` = 'US' 
   INNER JOIN show_texts 
           ON show_texts.company_id = companies.id 
              AND `show_texts`.`is_deleted` = 0 
              AND `show_texts`.`language` = 'en' 
              AND `show_texts`.`region` = 'US' 
   INNER JOIN show_region_counts 
           ON show_region_counts.show_id = show_texts.show_id 
              AND show_region_counts.region = 'US' 
    WHERE  ( ( `companies`.`id` NOT IN ( '77', '26' ) ) 
     AND ( `company_texts`.is_deleted = 0 ) 
     AND `companies`.id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT show_texts.company_id AS 
                                id 
                FROM   shows 
                       INNER JOIN `show_rollups` 
                               ON 
                                `show_rollups`.`show_id` = `shows`.`id` 
                                    AND ( `show_rollups`.`device_id` = 3 ) 
                                    AND ( `show_rollups`.`package_group_id` = 2 ) 
                                    AND ( `show_rollups`.`videos_count` > 0 ) 
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN `show_texts` ON 
                                    `show_texts`.`show_id` = `shows`.`id` 
                                        AND 
                                    `show_texts`.`is_deleted` = 0 
                                       AND 
                                    `show_texts`.`language` = 'en' 
                                       AND 
                                    `show_texts`.`region` = 'US'
                                       AND
                                    shows.is_browseable = 1 
                                    AND 
                                    show_texts.show_id IS NOT NULL 
                                    AND ( 
                                        `show_rollups`.`episodes_count` > 0 
                                        OR `show_rollups`.`clips_count` > 0 
                                        OR `show_rollups`.`games_count` > 0 
                                        )   


     ) ) 
    GROUP  BY companies.id 
    ORDER  BY Sum(show_region_counts.view_count) DESC 
    LIMIT  30 offset 30;
```

Now the problem is when I run this query in MySQL 5.1.73 before the upgrade, the query would only take around 1.5 seconds, but after the upgrade to 5.6.23, it now can take upward to 1 minute.

So I did an EXPLAIN of this query in 5.1.73, and I saw this:

[image: EXPLAIN with MySQL 5.1.73]
Enlarged version :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4ko0.jpg

And when I did EXPLAIN in 5.6.23 , I saw this :

[image: EXPLAIN with MySQL 5.6.23]
Enlarged version : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgBtA.jpg

I can see that in both cases, there is a full scan (type ALL) of the shows table, but is there something else I am not seeing that is causing the massive slowdown in 5.6?

Thanks
IS

Comment: I can't read those explain plans - would you paste them in as monospaced text?

Comment: Please write a bug report at http:bugs.mysql.com ; they want to know about cases where the new optimizer does worse than the old.

Comment: from the little i can make out, that second explain plan looks better than the first

Comment: also, additional helpful info can be retrieved via profiling: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html.  Is the hardware the exact same on both of these servers?

Comment: Sorry that the pics look small, but if you go to the direct URLs here, they are clearer :

5.1 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/c4ko0.jpg

5.6 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/CgBtA.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Without that, I will guess that you are missing this desirable index:

`show_rollups`:  INDEX(device_id, package_group_id, videos_count)

You have `LEFT OUTER JOIN show_texts ... ON ... show_texts.show_id IS NOT NULL`.  This is *probably* wrong for two reasons: (a) Don't use `LEFT` if you are not looking for `NULL`, and (b) the `NULL` test should be in the missing `WHERE` clause, not in the `ON` clause.

Getting rid of the `IN ( SELECT ... )` *may* help it on both machines:

```
SELECT  c.*
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  DISTINCT st.company_id AS id
            FROM  shows
            INNER JOIN  `show_rollups` AS sr ON sr.`show_id` = `shows`.`id`
              AND  ( sr.`device_id` = 3 )
              AND  ( sr.`package_group_id` = 2 )
              AND  ( sr.`videos_count` > 0 )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  `show_texts` AS st ON st.`show_id` = `shows`.`id`
              AND  st.`is_deleted` = 0
              AND  st.`language` = 'en'
              AND  st.`region` = 'US'
              AND  shows.is_browseable = 1
              AND  st.show_id IS NOT NULL
              AND  ( sr.`episodes_count` > 0
                      OR  sr.`clips_count` > 0
                      OR  sr.`games_count` > 0 ) 
      ) AS x
    JOIN  `companies` AS c ON x.id = c.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `company_texts` AS ct ON ct.`company_id` = c.`id`
          AND  ct.`language` = 'en'
          AND  ct.`region` = 'US'
    INNER JOIN  show_texts AS st ON st.company_id = c.id
          AND  st.`is_deleted` = 0
          AND  st.`language` = 'en'
          AND  st.`region` = 'US'
    INNER JOIN  show_region_counts AS src ON src.show_id = st.show_id
          AND  src.region = 'US'
    WHERE  ( c.`id` NOT IN ( '77', '26' ) )
      AND  ( ct.is_deleted = 0 )
    GROUP BY  c.id
    ORDER BY  Sum(src.view_count) DESC
    LIMIT  30 offset 30;
```

There is some chance that the JOINs will mess with the computation in `Sum(src.view_count)`.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the response. Regarding SHOW CREATE TABLE, if I check that on show_rollups, there is one unique index on these columns `show_id`,`package_group_id` and `device_id`  , not for device_id, package_group_id, and videos_count  . There is also the primary key for the id column , and no other indexes

Comment: Thanks Rick James, I made a minor correction in your SQL, and it works great and fast!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I can't make out the EXPLAIN screen-grabs on my display.

Without that, I'd wonder if the schemas for the tables changed at all, or of the database engines changed.  In particular, companies.id seems to be used as a primary key.

Comment: Sorry that the pics look small, but if you go to the direct URLs here, they are clearer : 5.1 : i.stack.imgur.com/c4ko0.jpg 5.6 : i.stack.imgur.com/CgBtA.jpg